# My Question is I want to redirect from this Login_Page__c object to another object Obj_A__c when redirect to objA it shows detail page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class Online_Admission_LoginPage {
public Login_Page__c lp{set;get;}
public Obj_A__c  B{set;get;}
public Online_Admission_LoginPage (){
lp=new Login_Page__c();
B=new Obj_A__c();
}
public pagereference Save(){
insert lp;
pagereference pg=new pagereference('/apex/'+B.id);
return pg;
}
}

<apex:page controller="Online_Admission_LoginPage">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Welcome to Devry University">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:inputField value="{!lp.Name}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!lp.Password__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:commandButton value="Register" action="{!Save}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you want to redirect to a standard detail page just have your Pagereference as '/'+B.Id. If you use it with /apex you are telling the platform to redirect to your custom Visualforce page.

Comment: Yes with the platform i am trying its possible or not

Comment: i am redirected through one object only when i select '/'+lp.id it redirects to detail page of that like that from this lp page i need to redirect to another s-object which is B.id when i redirecting it shows some error....!

Comment: Dont worry its got it i tryed done it

Comment: Yes that's what you get when trying to load up a record Id that doesn't exist.  I see that nowhere in your code you are actually inserting your Obj_A__c record. That's why you get a null attribute with your B.Id .  Isn't the Id of that record null at that point in time?